# Plugin setting a plane

Tags: flutter, dart, arcore

I am using Flutter for an AR app. This is the part of the code which creates a sphere:

```
 void _addSphere(ArCoreController controller) {
    final material = ArCoreMaterial(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 134, 244),
    );
    final sphere = ArCoreSphere(
      materials: [material],
      radius: 0.1,
    );
    final node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: sphere,
      position: plane.pose.translation + vector.Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
    );
    controller.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(node);
  }
```

From what I've seen in a few other examples, this part seems to work. But I get an error saying `plane` isn't defined, which I figured as it isn't defined anywhere in the code.

It makes sense that it is part of some package that needs to be imported, like the vector package:

`import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;`

But I can't find the `plane` equivalent of it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you haven't defined what the plane is.
You need to do something like this.

```
     void _handleOnPlaneTap(List<ArCoreHitTestResult> hits) {
       final hit = hits.first;
         _addSphere(arCoreController, hit);
     }

     void _addSphere(ArCoreController controller, ArCoreHitTestResult plane) {
       final material = ArCoreMaterial(
         color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 134, 244),);
     final sphere = ArCoreSphere(
       materials: [material],
        radius: 0.1,);
     final node = ArCoreNode(
       shape: sphere,
        position: plane.pose.translation + vector.Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
     );
     controller.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(node);
     }
```